Is there an error in my codes, my CSS hover effect isn't working in my browser display
I tried the codes, but it's not showing me the display I want.


@font-face {
  font-family: 'AlfaSlabOne-Regular';
  src: url('AlfaSlabOne-Regular.ttf');
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 63);
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
}

.navbar-img {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: transform 1.5s;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: 'AlfaSlabOne-Regular';
  font-size: clamp(3.5rem, 10cqi, 10rem);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  transform: translateX(-2rem);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.nav-link span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: color 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.nav-link :hover span {
  color: #ebe8c8;
  transform: translateX(2rem);
  transition-delay: calc(var (--i) + 0.2s);
}

@keyframes letterAnim {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    color: #fff;
  }
  50% {
    color: #E6A570;
    JAVASCRIPT: const links=[...document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link")] const navText=['About',
    'Clients',
    'Portfolio',
    'Careers',
    'Fun'] links.forEach((link, i)=> {
      navText[i].split('').forEach((letter, j)=> {
        const span=document.createElement('span') span.textContent=letter span.style.cssText=`--i: .$ {
          j
        }
        s` link.append(span)
      }
      )
    }
    ) P:S use any video or image of your choice. I just wanted the navigation to change color whenever I put my keyboard mouse on it.
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(2rem, 0);
    color: #ebe8c8;
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <video src="video-1.mp4" autoplay loop muted class="nav-video"></video>
    <img src="img.png" class="navbar-img">
    <nav class="nav">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 5</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>




Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so contributors can help you with your problem? Also please read how to ask a good question. You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance.

@Meet you can always try to edit the question yourself and move the code to snippet.

Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question accordingly and provide more details and clarity. Not working  is a poor description of any issue. What was expected? what result was achieved? How does the result differ from the expectation?

Is it because .nav isn't wide enough to show the elements moving? Use your browser's "inspect element" tool to show you the relevant element details.

@tacoshy thanks for insides but it was showing too many pending edits.

From what I can see, the main issue is that the image (being positioned absolutely) appears in front of the links and therefore the links are not hoverable. Styling the image with z-index: -1 resolves that.


const links = document.querySelectorAll('nav a')
const navText = ['About', 'Clients' , 'Portfolio', 'Careers' , 'Fun']

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].innerHTML = navText[i]
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1; /* moves it behind the links so that the links will be hoverable */
}

nav a {
  font-size: clamp(3.5rem, 10cqi, 10rem);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav a:hover {
  transform: translateX(-1rem);
  color: pink;
}
<div class="navbar">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/650/375/750">
  <nav>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </nav>
</div>




Brett, you should add some explanation to your code of what you changed/improved.

To begin with, there are quite a few issues with code.
First of all, there is a very much ambiguity here. Therefore, from the code, my conclusion about your expected result is a working letterAnim.
The first and foremost issue is that it's not even called, anywhere. Let's fix that by updating .nav-link:hover
.nav-link:hover {
    /* We don't need these unless an initial
       right shift is required */
 
    /* transform: translateX(-2rem);
       transition: transform 0.3s; */

    /* This adds letterAnim, which will be run once
       nav-link is hovered */
    animation: 700ms ease-in letterAnim forwards;
}

Not much has changed. That's because the way you have set up your JS is faulty. Either write each statement on a new line or add a breakpoint with ; after each statement. cssText also has extra spaces. With a bit more of fixing and formatting, we have this.
const links = [...document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link")];
const navText = ["About", "Clients", "Portfolio", "Careers", "Fun"];

links.forEach((link, i) => {
  link.innerHTML = "";
  navText[i].split("").forEach((letter, j) => {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = letter;
    span.style.cssText = `--i: .${j}s`;
    link.append(span);
  });
});

and now we have a beautiful wavy text animation.


const links = [...document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link")];
const navText = ["About", "Clients", "Portfolio", "Careers", "Fun"];

links.forEach((link, i) => {
  link.innerHTML = "";
  navText[i].split("").forEach((letter, j) => {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = letter;
    span.style.cssText = `--i: .${j}s`;
    link.append(span);
  });
});
@font-face {
  font-family: "AlfaSlabOne-Regular";
  src: url("AlfaSlabOne-Regular.ttf");
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 63);
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
}

.navbar-img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: transform 1.5s;
  z-index: -1;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: "AlfaSlabOne-Regular";
  font-size: clamp(3.5rem, 10cqi, 10rem);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  /* transform: translateX(-2rem);
  transition: transform 0.3s; */
  animation: 700ms ease-in letterAnim forwards;
}

.nav-link span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: color 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.nav-link:hover span {
  color: #ebe8c8;
  transform: translateX(2rem);
  transition-delay: calc(var(--i) + 0.2s);
}

@keyframes letterAnim {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    color: #fff;
  }
  50% {
    color: #e6a570;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(2rem, 0);
    color: #ebe8c8;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>HTML + CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <video src="video-1.mp4" autoplay loop muted class="nav-video"></video>
      <img src="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEjw7OZZ8Gb4mj2dovNLtuCuqHJ96rc2GYuDu7K58fCgNIgzjOsc5Fe6yYmmv90jqkKw3P4uLKUXUIaFZY8YToKVjHuteTpI4wBWO4wlB9Br57tcC_nef4IdDXR20svnFm03ZVs9712JnRTq9k9XigARaJI8umKV00nr2G5iLXpmk3y8L_1EXyhQbUuJwA/s1600/beautiful-cloudy-landscape-132023-thumb.webp"
        class="navbar-img" />
      <nav class="nav">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 5</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




why create an array out of querySelectorAll? It returns a Node List that you can iterate through with forEach without conevrting it to an array

@tacoshy and you'd be correct in thinking that. I just wanted to make as few changes as possible. Although there's some advantage to destructing the NodeList into an Array, as that opens up more methods. We are just using forEach here, so it doesn't really matter.
